# Linq query to fill ViewModel collection including child ViewModel collections

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to work out how to do a Linq query where you get a collection of objects and their child view model collections.

Let's say you have these models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string ParentName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<FirstChild> FirstChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecondChild> SecondChildren { get; set; }
}

public class FirstChild
{
    public int FirstChildId {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string FirstChildName {get; set;}
}

public class SecondChild
{
    public int SecondChildId {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string SecondChildName {get; set;}
}
```

And then you have some viewModels:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string ParentName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<FirstChild> FirstChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecondChildViewModel> SecondChildren { get; set; }
}

public class SecondChildViewModel
{
    public int SecondChildId {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string SecondChildName {get; set;}
}
```

Yes, the `ParentViewModel` would have one collection of models, and one collection of view models.

I would like to do a linq query that ends up populating a list of `ParentViewModel` with the child collections filled.

```
var result = (from p in db.Parent.Include(p => p.FirstChildren).Include(p => p.SecondChildren)
            select new ParentViewModel {
                ParentId = p.ParentId,
                ParentName = p.ParentName,
                FirstChildren = p.FirstChildren,
                SecondChildren = p.SecondChildren as SecondChildViewModel
            });
```

What would be the best way to handle that?

Comment: What's the problem with your solution (except that you can't cast `p.SecondChildren as SecondChildViewModel`)?

Comment: `p.SecondChildren` is type `SecondChild`, and I'm trying to assign it to `ParentViewModel.SecondChildren` which is type `SecondChildViewModel`. I get: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PublicationSystem.Model.SecondChild>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<PublicationSystem.ViewModels.SecondChildViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line

```
SecondChildren = p.SecondChildren as SecondChildViewModel
```

is the problem, you should simply handle it similar to `Parent` -> `ParentViewModel`, i.e. use projection:

```
SecondChildren = p.SecondChildren.Select(c => new SecondChildViewModel {
    SecondChildId = c.SecondChildId,
    ParentId  = c.ParentId,
    SecondChildName = c.SecondChildName
}).ToList()
```

Comment: So easy, so simple. (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Try using dataloadoption in Linq. Here is an example using your code:

```
var dataContext = new dataContext();
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<FirstChildren>( p => p.FirstChildren);
dlo.LoadWith<SecondChildren>( p => p.SecondChildren);
dataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;

var result = (from p in dataContext.Parent
            select new ParentViewModel {
                ParentId = p.ParentId,
                ParentName = p.ParentName,
                FirstChildren = p.FirstChildren,
                SecondChildren = p.SecondChildren as SecondChildViewModel
            });
```

Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a good example from Microsoft.